# Transform XML format to another XML format using XSLT (add one line in the output xml)

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and xml, I need to change the input xml to the output xml, assumes practically nothing is known in advance about the input and output XML.

Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ad:AcceptDataInfo xmlns:ad="http://www.abc.com">
<ad:Product>ABC</ad:Product>
<ad:Filename>test.pdf</ad:Filename>
<ad:AccountNo>123</ad:AccountNo>
<ad:Date>20140429</ad:Date>
<ad:Time>160102</ad:Time>
</ad:AcceptDataInfo>
```

output expected

```
<Documents>
<Document>
<Prop>
  <Name>Product</Name>
  <Value>ABC</Value>
</Prop>
<Prop>
  <Name>Filename</Name>
  <Value>test.pdf</Value>
</Prop>
<Prop>
  <Name>AccountNo</Name>
  <Value>123</Value>
</Prop>
<Prop>
  <Name>Date</Name>
  <Value>20140429</Value>
</Prop>
<Prop>
  <Name>Time</Name>
  <Value>160102</Value>
</Prop>
<File>test.pdf</File>
</Document>
</Documents>
```

xslt file

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <Documents>
        <Document>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </Document>
    </Documents>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <Prop>
      <Name><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></Name>
      <Value><xsl:value-of select="."/></Value>
    </Prop>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match=
  "Value[count(.|((//Value)[2])) = 1]">
    <File>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </File>
</xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the problem is, the output does not include the following line
    test.pdf
the value of the file tag is copied from filename tag

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Well, unlike [your previous question on this subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363159/transform-xml-format-to-another-xml-format-using-xslt), something **is** known in advance about the input here: apparently, it is supposed to contain a `Filename` element. Do we also know the namespace `"http://www.abc.com"` in which the input is provided?

Comment: The `Filename` element should refer to `<ad:Filename>test.pdf</ad:Filename>`. The namespace `"http://www.abc.com"` can be omitted since the output expected does not need any information about the namespace.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question which concerns the input, not the output. If the input will always be in the given namespace, you can declare this namespace in your stylesheet, assign it a prefix and address the input elements by their *qualified name*, e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="ad:Filename"/>` instead of the awkward and inefficient `<xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='Filename']"/>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem with your stylesheet is that you are matching `Value`, which is not in the input XML.

You could try the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <Documents>
            <Document>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
                <File><xsl:value-of select="child::*[local-name() = 'Filename']"/></File>
            </Document>
        </Documents>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <Prop>
            <Name><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></Name>
            <Value><xsl:value-of select="."/></Value>
        </Prop>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but using your provided xslt, the output xml still cannot get the filename, i.e. test.pdf, the File tag shows no value inside. `<File></File>`

Comment: Please have a look at http://xsltransform.net/3Nqn5Yj. It clearly shows the filename in the output.

Comment: Spotted the reason: just change the `<File><xsl:value-of select="child::*[local-name() = 'Filename']"/></File>` to `<File><xsl:value-of select="child::*[local-name() = 'FileName']"/></File>`, my updated input has Capital N, oops, sorry.